# Using standard scaffold form_for with restful resources with custom :controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a 'account roles' controller (for my AccountRole model) in my application using views generated by the standard scaffold generator. This controller is nested into my 'accounts' controller (for my Account model) using the following routing configuration:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :people, :controller => :account_roles
end
```

This results in routing helpers like `account_people_path` (`/accounts/1/people`) and `account_person_path` (`/accounts/1/person/1`). All well and good.

My problem comes in the default generated `_form.html.erb` partial. This file looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@account,@account_role]) do |f| %>
  <!-- Rest of form -->
<% end %>
```

I've customised this view to cope with the nested resources, but my use of the `:controller` option in my routing is causing me problems I think.

My view spec for the 'new' and 'edit' views (both of which use this partial) is resulting in the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `account_account_role_path' for #<#<Class:0x105334360>:0x105300c18>
```

I *think* what's happening here is that form_for is trying to 'guess' the route helper for these resources. I know I could override the url by using the `:url` option to form_for, but that feels like a bit of a cop-out.

Am I missing an obvious solution to this that allows me to combine the :controller routing option with `form_for`'s resource oriented style?

Comment: Is your model AccountRole or is it Person?

Comment: Hi @Vadim, the model is AccountRole. Will update question to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you can specify your route like so

```
resources :people, :controller => :account_roles, :as => "account_roles"
```

As per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

Comment: Was ideally hoping for something that solved this problem from the other end, allowing me to keep my friendly helpers, but I think you're right - this is the best option open to me!

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody like me is still looking for an answer to this question, I think I just figured it out.
What I did, in your case would be

map.resources :account_roles, :as => "people"
map.resources :people, :controller => "account_roles"

It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a somewhat older post, I was struggling with this as well.

My solution for this was to use the `url` option to specify the path.

In my case (which is slightly different, but still originates from the `controller: "AccountRoles"` stuff) I had to do the following:

```
resources :clients, controller: "AccountClients"


= form_for @client, url: clients_url(@client) do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  %p= f.submit
```

So you pass the `@client` variable to the form, but also set the correct url using `url:`.

In your case I reckon it would be:

```
<%= form_for([@account,@account_role], 
      url: account_people_path([@account,@account_role])) do |f| %>
  <!-- Rest of form -->
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps anyone coming across the same issue.